# Openfire XMPP Client Connection via Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, xmpp, ionic4, openfire

In order to test the client side connectivity with our Openfire XMPP server, the following test script (nodejs) was initially tested, which ran successfully.

```
async function connectX() {
    try {
        const keyPair = await XmppUser.generateKeys()
        XmppUser.connect(username, password, keyPairs).then(
           async user => {
                        user.getFriends().then(friends => {
                            console.log("List of Friends: ");
                            console.log(friends);
                            user.getChatHistory().then(history => {
                                console.log("Chat History: ")
                                console.log(history);
                                user.closeConnection();
                            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
                        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
            }
        ).catch(e => console.log(e));
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

connectX()
```

Output:

```
List of Friends:
[ 'test1.test@chat.company.io', 'test2.test@chat.company.io' ]

Chat History:
{ messages:
   [ { date: 2020-08-11T12:18:34.314Z,
       from: 'test1.test@chat.company.io',
       to: 'test6.test@chat.company.io',
       message: 'Hello! Received.',
       id: 'D255Q-132' }
] }
lastId: '1',
firstId: '1',
count: '1' }
```

However, when I run the script in an ionic angular app using the same ChatService class it leads me to the following CORS error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://chat.company.io/.well-known/host-meta' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

For information, *https://chat.company.io/.well-known/host-meta* exists and has the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<XRD xmlns='http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/xri/xrd-1.0'>
  <Link rel="urn:xmpp:alt-connections:httppoll"
        href="https://chat.company.io:443" />
</XRD>
```

The backend infrastructure includes an Nginx server and the chat server runs behind it with the following open ports: 443, 7070, 5222, 5223.

Please help in figuring out what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Possible CORS issue,
enable support for CORS in Openfire, server -> server settings -> http binding -> CORS section.